# Why is information not being stored in this variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the program:

```
def append(aList):
    return aList.append(10)

def main():
    mylist = [1, 2, 3]
    newlist = append(mylist)
    print(newlist,",", mylist)

main()
```

When I run this program, the output is:

```
None , [1, 2, 3, 10]
```

Why is there no information stored in the variable newlist?

Comment: That is not [how `append()` works](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Comment: Presumably because `aList.append(10)` returns `None`.

Comment: `append` does not return value.

Answer (score 1):

`append` does not return value, as described [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_append.htm).

This is probably more along the lines of what you want, though the example is fairly contrived.

```
def append(aList):
    aList.append(10)
    return aList
```

Comment: That modifies the original `list`, which probably isn't desired.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That's fine, I was just experimenting to see how/when the original parameter is changed.

Comment: I don't get all the negative votes though, sure it's a low level question but I don't see any rule against lower level questions

Comment: @Ovi One of the suggested criteria for downvoting is "does not show any research effort."

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 There are several ways and places of researches this site is one of those. However the first should be rather the Python documentation instead.

Comment: @GyörgySolymosi - So, the very act of posting a question is considered "research," automatically satisfying the "shows research" criterion and making it redundant? I don't think so. The OP in this case obviously saw an unexpected result and rushed to SO without so much as taking a few seconds to experiment with `append()` in the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out above `append()` return `None`.
append() works **`inplace`** instead.

So this is a solution:

```
from copy import copy

def append(aList):
    aList = copy(aList)
    aList.append(10)
    return aList

def main():
    mylist = [1, 2, 3]
    newlist = append(mylist)
    print(newlist,",", mylist)

main()
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 10] , [1, 2, 3]
```